# Histogram runs into object not found error

Tags: r, object, ggplot2, histogram

I am a student who is quite new to R and am having difficulty linking my dataset to the actual workspace. In particular, I am trying creating a histogram to show what life expectancy looks like across zipcodes of a state, but nothing is showing up.

This is what my code looks like:

```
install.packages("ggplot2")
library(ggplot2)


ggplot(data = df_mo, aes(x = life_expectancy)) + geom_histogram(color = "tomato")
```

Here is what my error message in the console states:

```
>ggplot(data = df_mo, aes(x = life_expectancy)) + geom_histogram(color = "tomato")
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'life_expectancy' not found
>
```

Here is what my dataset looks like:

[image]

This may be quite an elementary problem I imagine but I don't have a clue and have been at this for an hour. I've tried to look this problem up but everything i've seen has some additional bells and whistles added to the code or they are receiving a different error message.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The problem is in how the data was loaded - the headers were not treated as variable names but as cases.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the dataframe doesn't have the columns names that you want. As it is shown in the picture the names are `V1, V2, ...`. Something like:

```
colnames(df_mo) = df_mo[1,]
df_mo = df_mo[-1,]
```

should do the trick. Also should re-consider the way you are loading the data to R so it uses the first line as column names

Comment: This fix won't change the column types. Everything will currently be character type because it previously contained characters.  You'd be better fixing the initial import to get consistent column types

Comment: And. Don't install.packages every time you load ggplot. It's a once in a ?lifetime job. Simply load it in with library